# vb.net dateandtime get hour from now

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

I am looking to only get the starting hour.

Example:

if its **1:26 PM** i would need it to say **1:00 PM**.

Likewise, if it was **1:59 PM** i would need it to also say **1:00 PM**.

I can not seem to find some code that does that?

What do i need to include with my code below in order to do that above?

```
Dim tmpTime As DateTime = Format(Now, "h:mm tt")

MsgBox(tmpTime.Subtract(Format(Now, "mm")))
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new DateTime in this way

```
Dim tmpTime As DateTime = new DateTime(1,1,1,DateTime.Now.Hour, 0, 0)
```

Or this

```
Dim tmpTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-DateTime.Now.Minute)
tmpTime = tmpTime.AddSeconds(-tmpTime.Second)
```

now to the display the time you have just a format problem

```
Console.WriteLine(tmpTime.ToString("h:mm tt"))
```